# Can I make a 3 way calling app on android that allows the host to leave the other callers?

Tags: android, ios

I'm looking to build an app that does the following with traditional phone numbers:

A: Host Caller User B: Guest Caller 1 C: Guest Caller 2

(A) Calls (B) and (C) to connect a 3 way call.

After introductions, (A) leaves but (B) + (C) are still in the call together.

Is this theoretically possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be off-topic, But its not possible too. Whenever host leaves operators here in INDIA (PS dont know about others :p ) don't allow B and C to stay connected. Because tariff count will be hectic.  Whom to charge if host leaves? :)